# How to parse String into Integer upto two digits in java

Tags: java, string, parsing, integer

I have a String which contains values like **12:02**.Now i splitted this String based on **:**
and stored into array.Now i have to parse these array values into integer ..
On parsing to Integer from String my **02** becomes **2** only whereas in need **02**.
I am not getting how to do it.

Here is my code..

```
time = request.getParameter("time");
    System.out.println(time);

    String[] timearr = time.split(":");
    hourset=Integer.parseInt(timearr[0]);
    minuteset=Integer.parseInt(timearr[1]);
```

the value of minutset is giving difference..

Please help me.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: what error you got? of course, if you convert 02 to Integer, it will become 2

Comment: Do you need it just for output? It wouldn't make a difference otherwise.

Comment: Don't parse it if you want 02

Comment: Integer.parseInt() will do that(02 becomes 2) as 02 is similar to 2.Well what is your next step after converting to int?

Comment: See [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425183/how-to-always-round-in-two-decimals) for a similar problem.

Comment: The integer value does not make difference if you have '0' to at the start or not. The results will differ only if you treat them as strings

Answer (score 2):

You can use this one
If you want to see "02" on screen, format it with "%02d" pattern,
System.out.println("%02d", data)

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the value of a number (2) with its string representation (which can be 2, 02, 002, 000002, 0x02, whatever).

If you're dealing with time, use one of the classes that are more suitable for that, e.g. Date and Calendar.

If you really want to keep the '02', use a String and not an int.

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish two things: how number looks like and what number is. For example number 10 may look like "010", "10", "A", "1e1", but it is still the same number.

When you output number on screen with `System.out.printf("%d", minuteset)`, you are asking to format it with simplest format - "2". If you want to see "02" on screen, format it with `"%02d"` pattern:

`System.out.printf("%02d", minuteset)`

Comment: Just to clarify something to OP, the reason that "`%02d`" looks like the wanted number `02` is a coincidence. After the `%`, the `0` means pad with zeroes, `2` means make it at least two characters wide, and `d` means "decimal integer". E.g. `System.out.printf("%02d", 7);` outputs `07`.

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible. 02 is becomes 2 only..

Answer (score 0):

02 is not an Integer. 2 is an Integer. and you can not use Integer in this case. but if you want to store it in Integer, you must parse (you must write a custom parser that insert 0 to the first of one digit numbers) it again and show it as String.

Answer (score 0):

That is because an actual number has no leading zeroes as they make no sense at all and are superfluous. In case of integers, if you specify a leading zero yourself, then it'd be treated as an octal value.

In case you want to display the number with a leading zero, then you can use string formatting to achieve this.

```
int num = 123;
string leadingZeroes = String.format("%05d", num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Numeric data types are fundamentally incapable of distinguishing between `2` and `02`. The underlying bit pattern is identical. If you try `System.out.println(02);` you'll see `2` as the output, because it just can't tell the difference.

Whether or not to put zeros in front of the number is a formatting issue, and you can only control formatting of a number once you output it as a String again. E.g. try:

```
String time2 = String.format("%02d:%02d", hourset, minuteset);
```

And you will get "12:02" again.

Answer (score 0):

Golden rule: If you have numbers and you know that you will not do any math operations or database operations on the numbers, you should keeps those numbers as strings. I don't know if this is a real golden rule, but this is what I follow. lol.

Strings have many power ways to be manipulated, that's why I prefer String if no math/db operations will be done.